# How to add an icon before the name of the payment method

Tags: checkout, css, payment-methods, phtml

I want to add an icon before the name of the payment method the same as PayPal (https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/logo/PayPal_mark_37x23.gif), see the html below

```
<fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
    <dt>
            <input id="p_method_migsvpc_server" value="migsvpc_server" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="MigsVpc Server" onclick="payment.switchMethod('migsvpc_server')" class="radio" autocomplete="off">
            <label for="p_method_migsvpc_server">MigsVpc Server </label>
    </dt>
        <dd>
        <fieldset class="form-list">
    asdfdasf
    <ul id="payment_form_migsvpc_server" style="display:none">
        <li>
           adf You will be redirected to MIGS website when you place an order.        </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
    </dd>
        <dt>
            <input id="p_method_paypal_standard" value="paypal_standard" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="PayPal Website Payments Standard" onclick="payment.switchMethod('paypal_standard')" class="radio" autocomplete="off">
            <label for="p_method_paypal_standard"> <!-- PayPal Logo -->
<img src="**https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/logo/PayPal_mark_37x23.gif**" alt="" class="v-middle">Paypal
<!--<a href="https://www.paypal.com/hk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/Marketing/popup/OLCWhatIsPayPal-outside" onclick="javascript:window.open('https://www.paypal.com/hk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/Marketing/popup/OLCWhatIsPayPal-outside','olcwhatispaypal','toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, ,left=0, top=0, width=400, height=350'); return false;">What is Paypal？</a>
 PayPal Logo -->
</label>
    </dt>
        <dd>
        <ul class="form-list" id="payment_form_paypal_standard" style="display:none;">
    </ul>
    </dd>
        <dt>
            <input id="p_method_cashondelivery" value="cashondelivery" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="Cash On Delivery" onclick="payment.switchMethod('cashondelivery')" class="radio" autocomplete="off">
            <label for="p_method_cashondelivery">Cash On Delivery </label>
    </dt>

</fieldset>
```

I want to add an icon before migs, how can i do that? I had found this `app\design\frontend\default\template\migsvpc\server\form.phtml`, this only can append the icon after the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add DIV and add CSS class with Payment ICON

Add DIV as shown in below:

```
<dt>
    <div class="cashondelivery"></div> 
    <input id="p_method_cashondelivery" value="cashondelivery" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="Cash On Delivery" onclick="payment.switchMethod('cashondelivery')" class="radio" autocomplete="off"> 
    <label for="p_method_cashondelivery">Cash On Delivery </label> 
</dt>
```

Comment: Please provide more content to your answer. An example could be useful.

Comment: Add DIV as shown in below: <dt><div class="cashondelivery"></div>
            <input id="p_method_cashondelivery" value="cashondelivery" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="Cash On Delivery" onclick="payment.switchMethod('cashondelivery')" class="radio" autocomplete="off">
            <label for="p_method_cashondelivery">Cash On Delivery </label>
    </dt>

Comment: add to which file?